# Unable to display a dynamic table with Javascript using json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have to retrieve data in Json , then display it in a table. I tried several methods but they didn't work. This is my code for this function, can someone help me to figure out what is wrong with this code, because i'm getting nothing displayed, and no errors. Thank you

Code updated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>display the menu</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  
  var html = "<table border='1|1'>";

  for (var i = 0; i < obj.response.length; i++) {
          html+="<tr>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].id+"</td>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].restaurant_id+"</td>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].name+"</td>";
          html+="</tr>";

       }

   html+="</table>";
  $("div").html(html);
}

  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://deleted url sorry", true);
  xhttp.send();

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have to retrieve data in Json , then display it in a table. I tried several methods but they didn't work. This is my code for this function, can someone help me to figure out what is wrong with this code. Thank

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>display the menu</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.response[0].id + " " + obj.response[0].restaurant_id + " "+ obj.response[0].name;

}

var count = 0;
var html = "<table border='1|1'>";
for (var k in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
    {  ++count; }
//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.response[count].id + " " + obj.response[count].restaurant_id + " "+ obj.response[count].name;



        html+="<tr>";
        html+="<td>"+obj.response[count].id+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+obj.response[count].restaurant_id+"</td>";
        html+="<td>"+obj.response[count].name+"</td>";
        html+="</tr>";

     }

 html+="</table>";
$("div").html(html);
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "the URL I deleted it when posting", true);
  xhttp.send();


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: I'm unable to infer what you're asking. You don't get a desirable response from your link? You removed the link for us to replicate.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry i cannot show the link. I need the output to be displayed in a table. But instead i'm getting all the object.

Comment: You're trying to put table rows inside a paragraph element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do $('div').html() .... the div element doesn't exist in the page, so that nothing gets rendered

Comment: Oh my gad this so stupid. Thank you so much !! Im going to add the right code if somoene need it.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood, I didn't have a link to replicate.

---

There are a few things I notice in your code:

- Your data is clearly passed to the `p` because it is assigned in the AJAX callback.
- You've used a `For in` loop rather than a `For` with an iterator, though you are in fact iterating over an array of objects.
- There is no `$('div')` on the page for the `html` variable to put anything inside.

Here's an update to your script which should work fine:

```
function myFunction() {

    function myOtherFunction(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var html = null;

            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + data[i].id + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + data[i].restuarant + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + data[i].name + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';

            $('#demo').html(html);

        }
    } 



    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myOtherFunction(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("GET", "the URL I deleted it when posting", true);
    xhttp.send();

}
```

(You can even depracate the parent `myFunction()` if you just want this to happen on page load, but I'd still reccomend wrapping it in a `$(document).ready()`.

Also, consider the possibility of using a `document.createElement` and `.append()` (latter is in jQuery, former is core JS) for dynamically creating elements rather than passing in large DOM strings.)

---

Then, you need to remember to actually add a `table` element for your `<tr></tr>` containing your table data/JSON data to be placed inside.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>display the menu</h1>

        <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Your Header</td>
                    <td>Your Header</td>
                    <td>Your Header</td>
                    <td>Your Header</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="demo">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer. As kim82 answered me, the div element doesn't exist in the page. I just added it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>display the menu</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<div >

</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
   //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.response[0].id + " " + obj.response[0].restaurant_id + " "+ obj.response[0].name;
  // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.response.length
  var html = "<table border='1|1'>";

  //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.response[count].id + " " + obj.response[count].restaurant_id + " "+ obj.response[count].name;
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.response.length; i++) {
          html+="<tr>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].id+"</td>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].restaurant_id+"</td>";
          html+="<td>"+obj.response[i].name+"</td>";
          html+="</tr>";

       }

   html+="</table>";
  $("div").html(html);
}

  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://url deleted", true);
  xhttp.send();

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```